# How to show that $\sum_{g\in G} \phi (g) = 0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $\phi \ne 1  \in \hat G$  where G is   an abelian group , show  that $\sum_{g\in G} \phi (g) = 0$

My attempts  : It is  sufficient to show  that $g\in G\setminus\{1\}$ then there exists $\phi$ such that $\phi(g)\neq 1$.

After that  I am not able  to show that $\sum_{g\in G} \phi (g) = 0$

Any hints/solution  will be appreciated, thanks  in advance

Comment: $\phi$ is a character, as written $\phi \in \hat G$.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet  So the OP should have written $1 \neq \phi \in \hat G$. ($1/2 \neq 2 \in \Bbb{Z}$ is true and does not imply that $1/2 \in \Bbb{Z}$.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint** : If $S$ is your sum show that $S = \phi(h)S$ where $h \in G$ is such that $\phi(h) \neq 1$. It works even if $G$ is not abelian.

Comment: thanks for  answer  @Nicolas      can u u more  elaborate  ur answer...as  im not  getting  much

Comment: @stupid : Try to show that $S = \phi(h)S$. For this, use that $\phi$ is a morphism of groups and that $g \mapsto hg$ is a bijection.

Comment: @stupid : have you figured out ?

Comment: ya  i got its@Nicolas

Comment: @stupid : great !